# gcc ignores the explicitly specified linked libraries to be linked

Tags: c++, cmake, linker, undefined-symbol, vcpkg

I use CMake/vcpkg to manage my C++ programs dependencies, and ran into a linking issue on Linux.

My program depends on library X (`arrow` more specifically), and library X depends on another library Y internally (`RE2` in this case). When I linked my program to library X, the linking worked on macOS X (Apple clang 11) while didn't work on debian (g++ 9.3), reporting symbols in library Y cannot be found, and symbol missing were still reported by linker under Linux even if I explicitly linked library Y to my program directly.

Currently the only workaround I found is writing a useless function in my program using library Y, so that the linker will link the library Y. It seems to me the linker tries to be smart and avoid linking the library Y because it is not directly used by my program but reporting error when linking to library X due to it cannot find symbols in library Y used by X.

This doesn't seem to be a problem for this particular library since I had another library with the same case on Linux as well. One of the possible cause is I tried to make my program a shared library, but I don't know if it is relevant or not. Could some one shed some light on how this happens and how I may fix it?

Here is the error message reported:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib/libarrow.a(gdv_function_stubs.cc.o): in function `bool re2::RE2::FullMatch<>(re2::StringPiece const&, re2::RE2 const&)':
/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/include/re2/re2.h:368: undefined reference to `re2::RE2::FullMatchN(re2::StringPiece const&, re2::RE2 const&, re2::RE2::Arg const* const*, int)'
```

Comment: If `uuid` is **static** library, then `antrlr4` library, even if it is shared one, cannot remember linking with `uuid`. So, when link your program with `antrl4` you need to link with `uuid` too. You attempt to **describe** your code, but this description is quite **vague**. It is much better to post your **code** with **exact error message** it produces.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks for pointing this out, I did realize the description is too vague, and the problem is the error message itself is pretty common linking error message just saying something like `undefined reference to some function xxx'`, anyway, I updated my description with some detailed error message (I don't have the uuid issue error message at this moment so I used the RE2 one I have right now, the same issue)